# What's the reason the second code won't return what the first code successfully returns

Tags: ruby

I was doing a quick read up on arrays and some basic methods. And one of the exercise questions at the end of the reading gave me an array and asked to get the following output

```
=> [10, 8, 4, 2]
```

Here's the array:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

solution:1

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
numbers = numbers.select { |number| number.even? }.reverse
numbers.delete(6)
p numbers
```

---

But my question to you is why would the above code return the correct output but the following code won't?

---

solution: 2

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
numbers = numbers.select { |number| number.even? }
numbers.delete(6)
numbers.reverse
p numbers
```

I understand it's not the most fluent, but when I try to solve these exercises it's easier for me to separate everything and then clean up the code.

I expected it to pull the even numbers delete 6 from them and then print the reversed array.

Instead it pulls the even numbers, deletes 6, and prints the even numbers. Completely skips the .reverse

Comment: did you forget to write 'delete' in `numbers.(6)` ? Besides that, the only issue I see is thhat `numbers.reverse` doesn't actally change the array ... it returns a _new_ arrray that you have to assign to a variable.

Comment: This is a dumb question. (Not the question you posted; the question you're asked to answer. :-)) Why not `numbers.values_at(9, 7, 3, 1)` or `[2*numbers[4], 4*numbers[1], 4*numbers[3], numbers[1]]` or an infinite number of other possibilities?

Comment: Wow. max-pleaner, cary-swoveland, and tadman all in one place at one time. Time to call it a night!

Comment: @jvillian I think we all spend a good amount of time answering questions here XD

Answer (score 2):

As max says, `.reverse` doesn't change the array. Try, instead:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
numbers = numbers.select { |number| number.even? }
numbers.delete(6)
numbers.reverse!
p numbers

 => [10, 8, 4, 2]
```

Comment: This is a reminder to always check the documentation on if a method *returns a copy* or *modifies the object directly*.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have mentioned, `.reverse` doesn't change the array.

You either have to declare `numbers.reverse` as a new variable (i.e. `reversed_numbers = numbers.reverse`) or use `numbers.reverse!` (as demonstrated by jvillian) to change the value of the numbers variable itself at invocation.

Between the two, the latter method is more suitable.

Hope this helped!